# Bootstrap navbar - social media right corner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the navigation panel. I would like the social media icons to be in the right corner and without hover.

I've tried many solutions `padding` `margin` `justify-content-center` `justify-content-end` `flex`

I don't know how to do it to make it fully responsive. I've spent almost three hours trying to apply different solutions.

I would like such an effect
[image]

Thanks alot for help!

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  position: top;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #000000 !important;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/3/w3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top font">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
      </button>
      <a href="#up" class="navbar-brand"><strong>M</strong></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#about">O MNIE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">JAK PRACUJEMY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">PROJEKTY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">KONTAKT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-sm fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-sm fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you really want the `li` inside the `container` then add this code and check `.navbar .container { width: 100%;padding-left: 9%;}`. Otherwise, we can put the social icon outside the `li` and write code. Demo http://jsfiddle.net/3dcuz7ph/1/

Comment: @acmsohail Thank you very much for your time and help! I don't think your suggestion works well for me. I tried, combined and still have nothing....

Comment: Did you check the demo link which I mentioned above? check it from big screen.

Comment: @acmsohail Can I take a break between "Kontakt" and social media images to remain responsive? Can I make the mobile version still have social media images on top of it? I want it all to be very resposible!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/gBxJZp)

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: white;
  position: top;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.navbar li a,
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  color: #000000 !important;
  padding: 15px;
}

.navbar-nav li a:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active a {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

#brand {
  margin-left: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-light justify-content-center">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand mr-0 font-weight-bold" id="brand">M</a> 
    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar2">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-between align-items-center w-100" id="collapsingNavbar2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto text-center" id="nav-items">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">O MNIE</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">JAK PRACUJEMY</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">PROJEKTY</a> 
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">KONTAKT</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav flex-row justify-content-center flex-nowrap">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook mr-1"></i></a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

If you do run the snippet here on SO, please do it in full page view :)

Comment: Thank you very much! It actually works, but I have a few questions. 

Do you think I can use `margin` to set the position of logos and links? I would like to try to keep the `container` position all the time.

Can I make the mobile version still have social media images on top of it? I want it all to be very resposible!

Comment: @Pabloks, I've adjusted my example to match the image in your post so margins are fine. On the other hand, you can see bootstrap's [documentation on their ordering classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order) :)